# Sending data from import button directly to database

Tags: python, html, django, pandas

What i need to do is to import a txt file from the html:

```html
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/import_csv/">
      {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="document" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary shadow-sm"/>
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-md btn-primary shadow-sm mr-1"></input>
</form>
```

I tried also using button with an onclick event, but got the same error so i converted into input tag. The action on the form tag is the name of the function in the view.py, that does the following:

```
def import_csv(request):
context = {}
# data from the txt files
if request.method == 'POST':
    my_file = request.FILES['document']
    txtData = my_file.read()
    html = txtData.decode('utf-8')
    df = pd.read_csv(html, delimiter='\t+|\t\t', header=1)
    print(df)
    df.rename(columns={'Type d’enregistrement': 'Type', 'Historique du taux de glucose (mg/dL)': 'GlucoseHistorique'},
          inplace=True)
    df.drop('Taux de glucose scanné (mg/dL)', inplace=True, axis=1)
    df.drop('Insuline à action rapide (sans valeur numérique)', inplace=True, axis=1)
    df.drop('Insuline à action rapide (unités)', inplace=True, axis=1)
    df.drop('Nourriture (sans valeur numérique)', inplace=True, axis=1)
    df.drop('Glucides (grammes)', inplace=True, axis=1)
    df.drop('Insuline à action lente (sans valeur numérique)', inplace=True, axis=1)
    df.drop('Insuline à action lente (unités)', inplace=True, axis=1)
    df.drop('Commentaires', inplace=True, axis=1)
    df.drop('Glycémie avec électrode de dosage (mg/dL)', inplace=True, axis=1)
    df.drop('Cétonémie (mmol/L)', inplace=True, axis=1)
    df.drop('Insuline repas (unités)', inplace=True, axis=1)
    df.drop('Insuline de correction (unités)', inplace=True, axis=1)
    df.drop('Insuline modifiée par l’utilisateur (unités)', inplace=True, axis=1)
    df.drop('Heure précédente', inplace=True, axis=1)
    df.drop('Heure mise à jour', inplace=True, axis=1)
    csvFile = df.to_csv('log.csv', index=None)
# Parsing the data
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile)
    header = []
    header = next(reader)
    rows = []
    for row in reader:
    # rows.append(row[1])
        deviceDate = format_date(row[1])
        Device.objects.create(patientId=1, deviceId=row[0], hour=deviceDate, type=row[2], glucoseValue=row[3])

#creating the context
    context = {
           "file_content": json.dumps(txtData)  # moving the data to frontend
           }
return render(request, "index.html", context=context)
```

Earlier i tried with putting a local txt file in the main folder and converting it into log.csv(like in the code) and it worked. After i converted the logic to work from an import button(so i don't need to put the txt in the local folder everytime), everything went wrong. I tried to decode it, because it gave me "cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object".

Now i want to put it back into a csv, but the pd.read_csv gave me the following error:

"No such file or directory: 'John Doe\r\nID\tHeure\tType d’enregistrement\tHistorique du taux de glucose (mg/dL)\tTaux de glucose scanné (mg/dL)\tInsuline à action rapide (sans valeur numérique)\tInsuline à action rapide (unités)\tNourriture (sans valeur numérique)\tGlucides (grammes)\tInsuline à action lente (sans valeur numérique)\tInsuline à action lente (unités)\tCommentaires\tGlycémie avec électrode de dosage (mg/dL)\tCétonémie (mmol/L)\tInsuline repas (unités)\tInsuline de correction (unités)\tInsuline modifiée par l’utilisateur (unités)\tHeure précédente\tHeure mise à jour\r\n40344\t2021/08/30 01:48\t1\t\t92\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n40348\t2021/08/30 02:16\t1\t\t99\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n40354\t2021/08/30 03:06\t1\t\t109\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n40360\t2021/08/30 04:06\t1\t\t120\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n40371\t2021/08/30 06:28\t1\t\t122\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n40388\t2021/08/30 10:15\t1\t\t74\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n40390\t2021/08/30 10:21\t1\t\t74\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n40393\t2021/08/30 10:26\t1\t\t74\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n40401\t2021/08/30 12:01\t1\t\t142\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n40411\t2021/08/30 13:55\t1\t\t59\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n40419\t2021/08/30 15:28\t1\t\t214\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n40429\t2021/08/30 17:32\t1\t\t230\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n40434\t2021/08/30 18:23\t1\t\t196\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n40439\t2021/08/30 19:03\t1\t\t142\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n40441\t2021/08/30 19:07\t1\t\t141\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n40449\t2021/08/30 20:37\t1\t\t60\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n40453\t2021/08/30 20:58\t1\t\t42\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n40457\t2021/08/30 21:28\t1\t\t146\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n40461\t2021/08/30 22:05\t1\t\t193\t'"

I also tried printing the html and it's pretty well formated:
[image: html variable format]

I read that pd.read_csv can only see a path, so my question is: What method or what i should do to not get an error when trying to format the csv, so i can save each column in the database.

I hope it's not too long and thanks in advance for everyone trying to help me out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are importing to a pandas df first, then trying to save the df to a database.  Try this python code:

Connect to your database

```
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    engconnect = "{0}://{1}:{2}@{3}:{4}/{5}".format(dialect,user_uenc, pw_uenc, host, port, dbname)    
    dbengine = create_engine(engconnect)
    database = dbengine.connect()
```

Save your df to the database, in this case replacing the table if it exists

```
    df.to_sql('my_table_name', con=database, if_exists='replace')
```